# Camera2 pinch to zoom

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm struggling with trying to get pinch-to-zoom functionality working under Camera2; the API is not very helpful it has to be said and other libraries, like CameraKit don't do what I want to do.
I've looked at the various pieces of code on this and other websites and have come up with the following but I can't get anything working - not even a feed from the camera on the TextureView. (I'm not interested in saving the image from the camera, just to display and pinch to zoom). This isn't a problem with permissions, as I get asked whether I will allow camera access, its just that nothing appears.

The relevant section of the layout xml file is as follows:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frlayout"
    android:layout_weight="0.80"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
            <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/cameraView"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

While the salient portions of the mainactivity are here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public float finger_spacing = 0;
public int zoom_level = 1;

String camerId;
CameraCharacteristics characteristics;

int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;

private Size previewsize;
private Size jpegSizes[]=null;
private TextureView textureView;
private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
private CaptureRequest.Builder previewBuilder;
private CameraCaptureSession previewSession;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_ALL);

    }

    textureView=(TextureView)findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);

}

public  void openCamera()
{
    CameraManager manager=(CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try
    {
        camerId=manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        characteristics=manager.getCameraCharacteristics(camerId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map=characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        previewsize=map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            manager.openCamera(camerId, stateCallback, null);
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
 }

   private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener surfaceTextureListener=new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        openCamera();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    }
};


private CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback=new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice=camera;
        startCamera();
        // With previewBuilder set up, we can now call the fn to initialise ontouch
        setuptexturetouch();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(cameraDevice!=null)
    {
        cameraDevice.close();
    }
}

void  startCamera()
{
    if(cameraDevice==null||!textureView.isAvailable()|| previewsize==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    SurfaceTexture texture=textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
    if(texture==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewsize.getWidth(),previewsize.getHeight());
    Surface surface=new Surface(texture);

    //mPreviewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
    //mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

    try
    {
        previewBuilder=cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    previewBuilder.addTarget(surface);
    try
    {
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                previewSession=session;
                getChangedPreview();
            }
            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            }
        },null);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}

void getChangedPreview()
{
    if(cameraDevice==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    HandlerThread thread=new HandlerThread("changed Preview");
    thread.start();
    Handler handler=new Handler(thread.getLooper());
    try
    {
        previewSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewBuilder.build(), null, handler);
    }catch (Exception e){}
}

void setuptexturetouch()
{
    textureView.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event )
        {
            try {
                Activity activity = MainActivity.this;
                CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

                try {
                    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(camerId);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }

                float maxzoom = (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM))*10;

                Rect m = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
                int action = event.getAction();
                float current_finger_spacing;

                    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1)
                    {
                    // Multi touch logic
                    current_finger_spacing = getFingerSpacing(event);
                    if(finger_spacing != 0){
                        if(current_finger_spacing > finger_spacing && maxzoom > zoom_level){
                            zoom_level++;
                        } else if (current_finger_spacing < finger_spacing && zoom_level > 1){
                            zoom_level--;
                        }
                        int minW = (int) (m.width() / maxzoom);
                        int minH = (int) (m.height() / maxzoom);
                        int difW = m.width() - minW;
                        int difH = m.height() - minH;
                        int cropW = difW /100 *(int)zoom_level;
                        int cropH = difH /100 *(int)zoom_level;
                        cropW -= cropW & 3;
                        cropH -= cropH & 3;
                        Rect zoom = new Rect(cropW, cropH, m.width() - cropW, m.height() - cropH);
                     previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoom);
                        }
                        finger_spacing = current_finger_spacing;
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                            {
                        //single touch logic
                        }
                    }

                    try
                    {
                      previewSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, null);
                    }
                    catch (CameraAccessException e)
                    {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (NullPointerException ex)
                    {
                    //ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //throw new RuntimeException("can not access camera.", e);
            }
            return true;

        }

    });
}

private float getFingerSpacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback()
{

    private void process(CaptureResult result)
    {
       // Just a placeholder at present - the original code
       // had switch statements to see if an image had been saved
       // but I only want to view, not save.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureProgressed(CameraCaptureSession session,
                                    CaptureRequest request,
                                    CaptureResult partialResult) {
        process(partialResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session,
                                   CaptureRequest request,
                                   TotalCaptureResult result) {
        process(result);
    }

};


}
```

Comment: https://github.com/android/camera

Comment: https://github.com/jonathan-gomes/POCCamera

Comment: Thanks, but unless I'm missing something neither of these links has anything I can use.

Comment: try the second link and run it

Comment: I did, but it doesn't seem to support pinch to zoom.

Comment: post your code here now what you have tried so far, atleast your camera must be working , am i right ?

Comment: The code I am using is above, thanks.

Comment: did you not implement the example which i provided ?

Comment: I did, but without Pinch to Zoom it wasn't what I was after so I couldn't proceed with it.

Comment: initial problem is the camera not launching , i think you should fix that first , then i will be able to give u solution for pin to zoom in and out

Comment: Alright, I got it working. It showed up one surprise straight away - the orientation is wrong. The app is designed to work in landscape mode but the camera view is showing the view at 90 degrees and is squashed consequently.

Comment: please post screenshot here

Comment: and also update your code here